# How to include data for whiptail from file?

Tags: bash

How do I configure a `whiptail` dialog box using an input file `file.data`?

```
whiptail --menu "foo" 0 0 0 2>/tmp/out
```

The content of `file.data`:

```
"01" "Item 1"
"02" "Item 2"
"03" "Item 3"
"04" "Item 5"
```

`dialog` supports the `--file` option:

```
 dialog --file /tmp/file.data
```

but `whiptail` does not. Does it have something similar?

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll need to build your argument list manually.

```
menu_options=()
while read -r number text; do
    menu_options+=( ${number//\"} "${text//\"}" )
done < file.data

whiptail --menu "foo" 0 0 0 "${menu_options[@]}" 2>/tmp/out
```